# TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

Tags: python

Python 3.9.7
Running example code and getting the error: TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

```
lis=[(101, 153), (255, 827), (361, 961)]
from operator import itemgetter
max(lis,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Comment: I was unable to replicate this. Can you `print(max)`?

Comment: `max` is probably redeclared above this piece of code. try `print(max)` to see what it is a built-in function.

Comment: Use the built-in `max` instead of defining your own -- and don't `import *` from modules that do silly things like redefine `max`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import builtins
lis=[(101, 153), (255, 827), (361, 961)]
from operator import itemgetter
builtins.max(lis,key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

If it works, it should confirm that you redefined `max` somewhere along the way.

Comment: This direct call to the max function works as expected. For clarity sake, this is sample code, copied from a site because my own code also failed. I have to assume the sample code works in other environments. This is a new workbook and a refreshed python kernel, running in Spyder, installed via Anaconda. This helps me understand it is my install that has bugs, and that the example code has valid, working syntax. Thanks

Comment: Newbie error (not accepting the answer)... Thanks rudolfovic!

Comment: I found the culprit. As Samwise pointed out, this line was from a previous workbook and redefined the max function--- from pyspark.sql.functions import *